# python environment works with animate for single frames but not multiframe

Tags: python, animate

I am trying to achieve some complicated animations with the `animate` and `python` packages. I can use the `python` environment within an `animate` environment for single frames, for instance:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

Below changing numbers are displayed after clicking:

\begin{animateinline}[loop]{1}

\begin{python}
print("\LaTeX 0")
\end{python}

\newframe

\begin{python}
print("\LaTeX 1")
\end{python}

\newframe

\begin{python}
print("\LaTeX 2")
\end{python}

\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

works fine when compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`. However

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

Below changing numbers are displayed after clicking: 

\begin{animateinline}[loop]{1}
\multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{
\begin{python}
print("\LaTeX \i")
\end{python}
}
\end{animateinline}


\end{document}
```

where I have used the `multiframe` command to loop through `\i`, does not work.

If instead of using `python` I just type the text directly both options give the same result, which indicates the `python` environment is the cause of the issue.

Why is the `python` environment incompatible with `multiframe` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python` environment deals with verbatim content. Putting this sort of environment inside a command argument generally causes problems. A solution may exist, but it would probably be complex and involve a lot of catcode trickery.

Another option is to use the [`pythontex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) package, which I created to provide more functionality than the `python` package provides. `pythontex` provides a `\pyc` command that executes Python code inline. It usually works fine within command arguments, as long as `#` and `%` characters aren't needed. I've provided an example below.

Using `pythontex` involves a slightly different compile process. Whenever you have new/modified code that needs to be executed, run LaTeX, run pythontex.py, then run LaTeX again (more details in documentation). The `animate` package will give an error after the first LaTeX run, but will be fine after the second run. If there is no new/modified code, then just run LaTeX like normal; output is cached.

I assume that you will be using this to create more complex frames. In that case, you will probably want to create a Python function within a `pycode` environment, and then print the output of that function without the `\multiframe`, using `\pyc`. The example below also includes a demonstration of this.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

Below changing numbers are displayed after clicking: 

\begin{animateinline}[loop]{1}
\multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{
\pyc{print("\LaTeX \i")}
}
\end{animateinline}

\begin{pycode}
def my_func(x):
    return '\\textbf{' + x + '}'
\end{pycode}

\begin{animateinline}[loop]{1}
\multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{
\pyc{print(my_func("\LaTeX \i"))}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually saw there exists this `pythontex` package but I must say that needing a multi-step compilation put me off a little. I will look into this since it seems to provide a working alternative. Thanks again.